# Find largest square submatrix and largest rectangular submatrix in a sorted nxn matrix where the submatrix contains elements between x and y

Tags: algorithm, sorting, matrix, data-structures, time-complexity

You are given a nxn matrix of integers such that the entries of row are sorted in increasing order from left to right and entries of each column are sorted in increasing order from top to bottom like below.( I have included the matrix as image below)

[image]

Now given x and y with x < y I need to compute the largest square submatrix which contains numbers greater than x and less than y in O(n) complexity. For example x=7 and y=50, the following 3x3 matrix is the answer.(Included below as image)

[image]

Now given x and y with x < y I need to compute the largest square submatrix which contains numbers greater than x and less than y in O(nlogn) complexity. For example x=7 and y=52, the following 3x4 matrix is the answer.(Included below as image)

[image]

Please help me in solving the questions.

Comment: What do you mean by "Now given x and y with x"? I usually expected such a sentence to continue. For example, "Now given x and y with x equal to the row index and y equal the columns index". What are x and y?

Comment: @snow_abstraction I added details now in the question. Somehow i missed it earlier. Sorry.

Comment: so, square submatrix ? i cannot see a square in your matrix, that's like rectangle

Comment: how you can choose `y=50` and in the submatrix you have an element which is equal to `51` ?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi I have updated the image which contains square matrix and it is not necessary that 7 and 50 should be in matrix

Comment: now i can help you better, this is like young tablaeu

Comment: the idea based on moving diagonal, i will come back and write the answer as soon as possible

Comment: @ravitheja Are you sure that it's possible in O(n)? I can possibly think of O(n^2) or maybe O(nlogn).

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi can you post the solution??

Comment: @algrid yes for finding largest square subsquare matrix it is O(n) and for finding largest rectangual submatrix it is O(nlogn) if you get for largest rectangual submatrix please post the solution it will be helpful for me.